# dynamic schema value to DataSource.groovy

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

Is it possible to send dynamic values from Controller/Domain classes to DataSource.groovy? 
Ex: `default_schema = ${someConfig.default_schema}`

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. DataSource is loaded when the app starts up. There is no way to change this configuration in the run-time.

If your objective is to externalize Datasource configuration, you can use [JNDI](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#JNDIDataSources) like:

```
dataSource {
    jndiName = "java:comp/env/myDataSource"
}
```

and define the data source in web-app/META-INF/context.xml.